# Ansible to become an user for a particular task in a playbook

Tags: shell-script, ansible

Is there a way to use remote_user inside a playbook for a particular task?
This is for a corporate environment, so I have very limited access (i.e. no access to /etc/sudoers) or those kind of files.

I need a solution to this:

control node is = myserver@xyz | can ssh without password(keybased) into  weblogic@server1 and chandru@server1

task 1 : has to be run by weblogic

task 2 : has to be run by chandru

right now I am using two playbooks to achieve a simple task

```
playbook1.yml -u weblogic ( for the first task)
playbook2.yml -u chandru ( for the second task)
```

Once I am into the weblogic user, I can't become_user or become_sudo to chandru.

My control node can ssh without password to both the ids (chandru and weblogic) without needing a password.

Comment: If you can't become_user or become_sudo, how do you intend to escalate without a new login session?

Comment: Fix the title. You don't want to "**become** a user for a particular task". What you describe is **logging** as a different **remote_user** for a particular task.

Answer (score 3):

[Keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) *remote_user* can be used also in tasks. Test it e.g.

```yaml
  - command: whoami
    register: result
    remote_user: weblogic
    become: false
  - debug:
      var: result.stdout

  - command: whoami
    register: result
    remote_user: chandru
    become: false
  - debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

---

There are three entities involved in the process

1. A user who is running the playbook (No1)
2. A user who is logging into the remote host (No2)
3. A user who No2 can become (No3)

- The variable *remote_user* defines No2. If *remote_user* is not defined No2 is No1
- Setting *"become: true"* says No2 shall escalate to *become_user* No3 (default: root). If *"become: false"* Ansible is running as No2 at the remote host.

As a result, what you want is to **log** as a different *remote_user* (No2) to the remote host and **not become** (escalate) to a different *become_user* (No3). This also explains *"become: false"* in the tasks.